# Parallelise string replace in pandas

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numba

I have two pandas dataframes. One contains text, the other a set of terms i'd like to search for and replace within the text. There are many permutations of the text where the same word can appear multiple times in the text and have multiple terms.

I have created a loop which is able to replace each word in the text with a term however it's very slow, especially given that it is working over a large corpus.

My question is:
Is there a way of running the below function in a parallelised for speed? Alternatively could the function use Numba or some other type of optimisation to speed it up? NB note the fact that there can be many permutations within the text that need replacing.

Example text dataframe:

```
d = {'ID': [1, 2, 3], 'Text': ['here is some random text', 'random text here', 'more random text']}
text_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Example terms dataframe:

```
d = {'Replace_item': ['<RANDOM_REPLACED>', '<HERE_REPLACED>', '<SOME_REPLACED>'], 'Text': ['random', 'here', 'some']}
replace_terms_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Example of current solution:

```
def find_replace(text, terms):
for _, row in terms.iterrows():
    term = row['Text']
    item = row['Replace_item']
    text.Text = text.Text.str.replace(term, item)
    return text
find_replace(text_df, replace_terms_df)
```

Please let me know if anything above requires clarifying. Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vectorized method: [Series.replace(lst1, lst2, regex=True)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html)

```
In [90]: (text_df.Text
                 .replace(replace_terms_df.Text.tolist(), 
                          replace_terms_df.Replace_item.tolist(),
                          regex=True))
Out[90]:
0    <HERE_REPLACED> is <SOME_REPLACED> <RANDOM_REP...
1               <RANDOM_REPLACED> text <HERE_REPLACED>
2                          more <RANDOM_REPLACED> text
Name: Text, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful, produces the correct answer and looks faster. It still takes awhile to run given the size of the data, is there anything else that would help? thank you

Comment: @avocet, I don't know faster Pandas approach for this case... AFAIK Numba doesn't work for strings. One could try to write a Cython function, but I have no experiense with Cython...

Comment: Thanks MaxU, your help is appreciated. Just wondered if I could follow up. When trying it on my data I get the following error - 'sre_constants.error: multiple repeat at position' I'm guessing this to do with the regex? If you know how to solve I'd really appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: @avocet, i don't think i can help without a __reproducible__ sample ...

Comment: I understand, i'll have a think on how to reproduce. The replacement items include *s could this cause an issue? If i turn the regex=True parameter off, it seems to work. Would this cause any issues?

Comment: @avocet, yes, asterisk (`*`) - is a special RegEx symbol, so you might want to escape it by a backslash character...

Comment: Thank you, makes sense. Apologies I'm not sure sure how to add an escape.. :(

Comment: @avocet, replace `'*s'` --> `'\*s'`